# rosdep all packages

Tags: ros, rosdep, build, packages, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've recently been working with some experimental packages created for ROS and amd compiling these from source. Quite a few of these packages seem to have dependencies, so naturally I have been using the `rosdep install [package]` command. However, this seems a bit tedious given the amount of packages in the workspace.

I was wondering if there was a quicker way to do this or is this the standard way? - Something along this lines of install all dependencies for packages within a specific folder or similar.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202443/rosdep-all-packages/) by [twix](https://answers.ros.org/users/21566/twix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-02-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try:

```
rosdep --help
```

Quote:

```
[...]
  -a, --all             select all packages
[...]
  --from-paths          Affects the 'check', 'keys', and 'install' verbs. If
                        specified the arugments to those verbs will be
                        considered paths to be searched, acting on all catkin
                        packages found there in.
```

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2015-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [twix](https://answers.ros.org/users/21566/twix/) on 2015-02-04**:
Thanks! I was trying to get to this same set of instructions by just typing `rosdep` but it was giving me the commands instead of the arguments obviously. *facepalm*

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2015-02-04**:
Oh, I see. Yeah, it's strange that when run without any arguments, rosdep only prints half the help page.